# How to open Eclipse project as read-only?

Tags: eclipse

Does anyone know is there a way to open a project in Eclipse in read-only mode? If there is a lot of similar projects open it is easy to make changes to a wrong one.

Comment: This is something I'd like to do as well. I'd like to be able to be able to open some FOSS projects distributed as archives (they are not working copies) as projects within Eclipse, but also to ensure that the files stay exactly as downloaded.

Comment: +1 Need this also today.

Comment: @serg are you satisfied with my answer? If yes mark it as accepted please :)

Answer (score 5):

Putting project in read-only mode is really useful, when you make another instance from the previous project. So you copy all files from old project, then make changes in the new instance. It's really simple to edit files from old project by mistake (they have the same names)!

Serg if you use linux, I suggest to put all files in read only mode with chmod in terminal:

```
sudo chmod 444 -R /path/to/your/project
```

After this operation Eclipse will tell you that file you are trying to edit is in read-only mode. I think that's enough to make the previous project safe :)

Answer (score 3):

One sub-optimal solution is to make the project directory read-only in the file system in the underlying OS. I'm not sure how eclipse will react though.

Comment: +1 This worked for me, I made a project's directory read-only and when I tried to edit a source code file, eclipse promoted me asking if I want to make the file writable...

Answer (score 2):

This feature is called "binary projects" and is provided by the eclipse plug-in developement environment (PDE). Note that this only works for eclipse plug-in project, see

[Contributing to Eclipse - Principles, patterns and plug-ins](http://books.google.com/books?id=0X6wZRd5OOQC&pg=PA11&lpg=PA11)

or

http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#importplugins_binary

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the close project/open project feature : close all projects and only open the one you need to work on ?