# How to set Eclipse project as read-only?

Tags: java, eclipse, readonly

In a single file it can do *right click > Properties > mark 'Read only' under Attributes* , how can I do the same on all the project files ? I found [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97013/how-to-open-eclipse-project-as-read-only) from '08 but with no enough answer .

Comment: You can set each package as read-only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open Eclipse project as read-only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97013/how-to-open-eclipse-project-as-read-only)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If all else fails just use the operating system to set the project folder as read only.  Eclipse will prompt you if you try to modify a read only file.

Answer (score 7):

In Eclipse release 4.5.1 ("Mars"; and probably earlier releases), you *can* change multiple files by selecting the "src" folder and going to Properties>Resource>; then change the "Write" column under "Permissions".

In newer versions of Eclipse, you can find the option read-only under "Attributes", in Properties>Resource>;.

[image: Eclipse src folder Attributes]

Comment: This is same as setting the 'src' directory to read-only in operating system.

Comment: While the OP explicitly asks for making it _read-only_, I found it better to mark it _derived_ insted. Eclipse will warn if you try to edit a derived file, but its not marked read-only on the file system, so you can re-generate those files. OFC this is only for generated files.

Answer (score 3):

I don´t think Eclipse has that functionality built in. It just uses the files on the filesystem.

I think you have to do that in the filesystem of the particular OS you are using.